# "file not sent" from Android to Macbook, whereas they're paired

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth, data-transfer, android

I'm trying to send a file from Android to Macbook via bluetooth. I pair them successfully and when I'm sending a file from Android, it just ends up saying "file not sent". In the Macbook does happen nothing at that time, no pop up window or something.

That's it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In **System Preferences > Sharing > Bluetooth Sharing**, ensure that **Folder for accepted items** is set to something. If it isn't set, incoming file transfers are rejected automatically.

[image]

Comment: Any other things I should check?  Bluetooth and Bluetooth sharing are on, 'when receiving' is 'ask', accepted items folder is set and Android phone paired but still file is still rejected.

Comment: Also Bluetooth sharing can get turned off somehow. I checked mine and it was off even though it was on yesterday.

Answer (score 6):

After updating to macOS Monterey v 12.1 I also had this problem.

For me, I needed to turn OFF **Bluetooth Sharing**, turn down **System Preferences** and then turn ON **Bluetooth Sharing** again and it did work.

Comment: The same. After I toggled it off and on it started to work

Comment: what the heck?! I had to turn it off and on for it to work again. there is a bug here that Apple has to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem before over the last year or two and I think I gave up last time. But I needed to get a photo from my Android phone to my M1 Air today and tried again for a couple of hours.

There seems to be a very sneaky bug in macOS. I had "When receiving items" set to "Ask What to Do":
[image: Ask What to Do]

Finally I randomly decided after much frustration to just try setting it to "Accept and Save":
[image: Accept and Save]

To my shock it suddenly worked! Sensing it could be a bug I turned it back to "Ask What to Do" and that now also works.

I think some internal flag was set or changed during an previous OS update. I updated to Sonoma just a few days ago but I'm sure I had this problem before that, but I'd also had it working at some point when the computer was new, so probably an intermediate OS release.

I do see several crashes of `bluetoothd` in `Console/rash Reports`, even from previous days when I wasn't using Bluetooth at all. I don't know what to make of that.

Comment: Please note the sharing functionality does not work if you create a folder in your user home directory `~/bluetooth_shares/` at the same level as desktop... I ended up creating a new folder inside of my downloads folder `~/Downloads/bluetooth_shares/`  and that works after flipping thru the picklist options.

Comment: @JayRizzo: Interesting. I don't seem to have a `bluetooth_shares` currently anywhere on my system.